# Calling member function of templated member

Tags: c++, templates

This program compiles fine but seg faults when running the `value->getSmall` in `Period::display()`. I'm working on linux with g++. I've provided a `getSmall` function for all the classes that may be used as `T`. Just to be sure I added the debug lines and found that the segfault is caused when type of value ie `T` is Class* . I came across some FAQ which mentioned some problems like calling independent values in a templated context but I'm clueless about how to solve this.

```
using namespace std;
template <class T> //T is the class which has to be related & referenced to by period
class Period
{
    T value;    
public:

    void display()
    {
            cout<<setw(5)<<"| "<< value->getSmall() << "|";

                size_t len;  //for debug
                int s;        //for debug
                char* p=abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(value).name(), 0, &len, &s);   //for debug
                cout<<setw(5)<<"| "<< p << "|";       //for debug
    }

};


class Class
{
    string name;
    timeTable<Teacher*> tt; //class timetable contains pointers to teachers
    vector<Teacher::teachTimePerClass> teachers; //set of all teachers teaching in a Class with corresponding total time

    //assigns a teacher to a period in a day
    bool assign(dayNames day,int periodNum,Teacher *teacher)
    {
        tt.assign(day,periodNum,teacher);       //assign the value in this Class's timetable
        teacher->assign(day,periodNum,this);    //update the teacher's timeTable
    }

public:
        static vector<Class*> Classes; //dont forget to destory it at the end!!


    string getSmall()
    {
        return name;
    }
};
vector<Class*> Class::Classes;
```

Comment: 1. Why are you even using pointers. 2. Where's the code that segfaults.

Comment: Currently I don't see why display() should segfault besides get small not returning anything. Your compiler should warn you about this though.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus 1)I have a main list of many Class maintained as a vector. The period is supposed to be 'linked'  to a specific Class and hence I though i might use pointers. What do you recommend instead?

2) the segfault doesn't occur if i comment out the value->getSmall() part

Comment: There were no warnings at all.

Comment: It's impossible to say what's going on, since your code never instantiates the `Period` template. Give us the real code that's causing your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assume `T` to be a pointer, but never give it a value in `Period`.

That way you have an uninitialized pointer that is likely to segfault.

Comment: Bull's eye! I forgot to complete one of the assign functions which fills the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
string getSmall()  // Class::getSmall()
{
  //return name;
}
```

If this is your real code than, your `return` statement is missing; which is an undefined behavior. Luckily you are getting a segmentation fault. This kind of bugs are difficult to trace. You should provide `-Wall` option while compiling with `g++`; it will suggest such kind of logical errors as warnings. [See demo](http://www.ideone.com/bzjbQ).

Comment: sorry, did that to see if it is the return value that causes the problem.